# I have a problem with DNS after upgrading from WSL1 to WSL2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a DNS issue after updating from WSL1 to WSL2.  I can't ping even google.com. The only address that I am able to reach is the loopback address.

Here is what I've tried:

1. I created the `/etc/wsl.conf` file with the following content:

   ```
   [network]
   generateResolvConf = false
   ```
2. I removed the existing `/etc/resolv.conf` file and created another one with the following content:

   ```
   nameserver 8.8.8.8
   nameserver 8.8.4.4
   nameserver 1.1.1.1
   ```

But unfortunately without success as I always got the following message:

```
> ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: If you look at the WSL2 issue list on Github, many people have reported this issue or a variation of this issue.   In many cases, a full Windows reboot resolves the issue. Are you able to ping a host using an IPv4 address?

Comment: @fpmurphy thanks for your reply, in fact i saw all bugs open in Github about this problem for weeks, none of them has helped me.
no am not able to ping any host using an IPv4 and here is the error message :
**From 172.21.x.x icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable**

Comment: That would seem to suggest a network configuration issue either in WSL2 or Hyper-V.  Using PowerShell `Get-NetAdapter`, do you see a `vEthernet (WSL)` entry and is it marked as up?

Comment: @fpmurphy Can I ask you to revert your edit?  Those spaces in the code block were the correct markdown formatting for a code block inside a list.  When you removed them, the list reverts to no indent, but it should be indented to align with the rest of the list.  Also "problems" or "a problem" are both correct, as is (marginally) a hyphen (technically should be an em-dash) to offset the other phrase.  So I'd propose it would be best just to revert your edit entirely.

Comment: This appears to be unrelated to DNS.  If you can't ping any host by IP then DNS will fail as a result of that.  `Destination Host Unreachable` suggests that linux doesn't know where to send the packet.  This can be because routing is not properly configured. (use the `ip route` command to check).  However WSL2 (unlike WSL1) is a linux virtual machine running on Windows. It's possible that the virtual machine doesn't have networking for some reason.  That would make this a Windows problem more than a Linux one.

Comment: @fpmurphy yes it's shown and it's up.

Comment: @PhilipCouling i totally agree with you it could be a firewall issue but i didn't get how to resolve it.